# How do I determine the order of "properties" with swagger-autogen in node.js?

Tags: node.js, properties, swagger, mongoose-schema

For some reason, swagger-autogen is reversing the order of my properties in my swagger.json output file. For example, I have a simple 'user' mongoose schema set up with only 'username' and 'password' properties. When I run swagger-autogen, my PUT swagger-docs populate with the password first and the username last. I need username first and password last. I have to manually fix it in my swagger.json file every time I run swagger-autogen. Is there a way to determine properties order in my swagger.js or possibly on my controllers functions so I don't have to alter it every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

swagger-autogen doesn't have an option to determine the order of parameters. In your case, you have two options:

Option 1: Try reordering your mongoose schema.

Option 2: Manually declare the parameter in the endpoint that contains the `put` method as follows:

```js
app.put('/somepath', (req, res) => {

    /*  #swagger.parameters['body'] = {
            in: 'body',
            required: true,
            schema: {
                username: "user",
                password: "1234"
            }
    } */

    ...
})
```

See more about swagger-autogen [parameters here](https://github.com/davibaltar/swagger-autogen#parameters)

If none of the options work, send us a link to a sample project or post here some pieces of your code that reproduces this problem. That way it's easier to help you.

**disclaimer:**
working for swagger v1, v2, but not for v3

Comment: ` Try reordering your mongoose schema.`, that doesn't seem to work.